# Identifying a semiconductor part

Tags: identification, components

I have a triode with the following markings that I want to replace.

[image]

A similar component would suffice in my case. I am also looking for a datasheet to figure out the purpose of this component.

I am interested in is what this manufacturer logo "'C'hk" stands for. I have been unsuccessful at finding out for the last hours. I hope someone in this community recognizes this logo and the manufacturer. What could be this component's purpose?

Some extra information:
This is part of a servo board circuit. It stands in between the power in  and Vdd of a STM8 chip:

[image]

Photo of the board:

[image]

The three capacitors on the left have been desoldered by me and the three pins used to have a potentiometer soldered to them.

Comment: It is likely a 3.3V LDO for powering the STM8 device.

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer  the powerline that powers the STM8 also provides voltage to a potentiometer that tracks the servo's position. I think you are right with your guess. thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Please add a board photo, "triode" can mean a lot of different things (packages of various sizes). Especially the case dimensions, pin layout and logo are needed!

Comment: @datenheim good idea. I have added a photo and one can even see the markings.